# How to display a Modal form in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I have a Windows 8.1 WinRT app.
I want to have a XAML control in which i can have xaml controls like a button, textblock, listbox, etc.

I want to be able to load this XAML control in any page from the app. But i want it to appear as a modal, on top of the current page  over a black overlay.

How can i load a Xaml control on top of the current page?
Is there a way ot interact from this overlay with the other controls in the current page?

Example: while on a page, i want to open the modal and tap a button which will fill a form in the current page with test data.

Comment: have you looked at the Popup control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can host your controls in a [ContentDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.contentdialog.aspx). Visual Studio has a ContentDialog template which you can use to create the dialog like you would a UserControl. You can then launch it modally on top of any page:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ContentDialog1 cd = new ContentDialog1();
    cd.TestData = "Lorem ipsum";
    await cd.ShowAsync();
}
```

Comment: How can i add a black overlay with opacity so that it covers the whole screen?

Comment: If you want to roll your own rather than use the standard ContentDialog you can create a UserControl with your controls and black backround then show it in a Popup.